# Highlight Specific Button Upon Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a quiz app, and for a certain part of it I would like for some of the answers to be highlighted upon loading of the page.

These are the buttons:

```
<input type="hidden" name="correct_answer" value="<?php echo (isset($correct_answer)) ?   $correct_answer : 'no corect answer';?>">
<button name="answer" value="A" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">A</button>
<button name="answer" value="B" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">B</button>
<button name="answer" value="C" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">C</button>
<button name="answer" value="D" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">D</button>
<button name="answer" value="E" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">E</button>
```

You can see I'm loading a hidden element with the correct answer inside it.

All the back end works just fine, But I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Is it possible to do this in native JS or is jQuery a must?
Also, how do I go about doing this? How do I make sure the CSS class is added to the right element?

**EDIT:**

This is the code I ended up using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("<?php echo $correct_answer;?>").style.backgroundColor = "green";
</script>
```

Comment: So you want some of the correct answers to be highlighted on page load?

Comment: I want a specific one to be highlighted.

Comment: You could probably change the color of the specific button on page load but I don't know about highlighting something.

Comment: OK - Let's go that way. How do I go about it?

Comment: jQuery would simplify the code, but note that anything you can do in jQuery can also be done in JavaScript, because jQuery is written in JavaScript.

Comment: Obviously true - But will be lengthier, usually. Kind of like writing a Halo 4 in APL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already rendering the page with PHP, why not just have it add a class to those elements you want highlighted.

```
<button name="answer" value="A" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg <?php if ($correct_answer === "A") { ?>highlight<?php } ?>">A</button>
```

Then style that class:

```
.highlight {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Even if you were to use javascript to solve this, adding a class is far better than adding styles to an element. The class is more semantic and can be easily restyled without having to dig through your code.

Comment: This is the direction I was heading. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with vanila javascript using the backgroundColor,

So your js code would look like:

```
document.getElementById("answer1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sccqem9d/)

Please note that I have set Id for one element, however you can set for all elements and use that Id whose background is to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure JavaScript solution that will work with your existing HTML:

```
var correct= document.getElementsByName('correct_answer')[0].value;
var buttons= document.getElementsByName('answer');
for(var i = 0 ; i < buttons.length ; i++) {
  if(buttons[i].value===correct) {
    buttons[i].style.background= 'red';
    break;
  }
}
```

Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/qw7qhvnq/

Comment: Thanks, But @Soviut kind of hit it out of the park.